# Finding text in a string then using values from other cols based on that result R

Tags: r

Basically I'm wondering how to check if certain characters exist inside a string within a col in a dataframe...if they do I'd like to put the value from another col (A) into a new Col (C) or....if they don't I'd like to put the value from another col (B) into Col(C)..

A simple example is:

```
COLTEXT     COLA    COLB     COLC
paulx       useifx  useify   useifx
Pauly       useifx  useify   useify
Pauly       useifx  useify   useify
Pauly       useifx  useify   useify
Paulx       useifx  useify   useifx
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Thats was a data.frame i used

```
df0 <- read.table(text="COLTEXT     COLA    COLB     COLC
paulx       useifx  useify   useifx
Pauly       useifx  useify   useify
Pauly       useifx  useify   useify
Pauly       useifx  useify   useify
Paulx       useifx  useify   useifx", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)


df <- df0 [,-4]
```

For your data.frame (df)

```
df[grep("x", df$COLTEXT), "COLC"] <- df[grep("x", df$COLTEXT), "COLA"]
df[-grep("x", df$COLTEXT), "COLC"] <- df[-grep("x", df$COLTEXT), "COLB"]
```

Comment: I need to reference the actual column name not "COLC"....ie DF$COLC. when I run this i get an error....Error in `*tmp*`[[jj]] : subscript out of bounds..?

Comment: @PaulBeales, I added a data.frame I used to do this. Try it now. P.S. be carefoul with `DF` and `df`. You can also change the destination column "COLC" to another what you want just changing it´s name